# Error with SQL Server request using data.sqlclient in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am trying to run a SQL query on my UWP code. I don't use Linq or EF. The connection to the base work and the simple requests work. This causes me problems: in a first time i populate a listview with the result of a simple request, i choose an element and i click on a searchin button. This request is call with an error:

```
    static public ObservableCollection GetGaz(string connectionString, 
         string selectedOrder)
        {

            string GetGazQuery =

            "SELECT " +

                    "tbl_607_gaz_type.gaz_type," +
                    "tbl_607_theorical_content.theorical_content," +
                    "tbl_607_made_tolerance.made_tolerance," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.gaz_lifetime," +
                    "tbl_607_gaz.gaz_comments," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.poste_number, " +
                    "tbl_607_order.order_number" +

                "FROM " +
                    "tbl_607_provider join tbl_607_order on tbl_607_provider.ID = tbl_607_order.FK_ID_provider " +
                    "join tbl_607_order_details on tbl_607_order.ID = tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order" +
                    "join tbl_607_gaz on tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_gaz = tbl_607_gaz.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_gaz_type on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_gaz_type = tbl_607_gaz_type.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_made_tolerance on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_made_tolerence = tbl_607_made_tolerance.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_theorical_content on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_theorical_content = tbl_607_theorical_content.ID " +

            "WHERE " +
                "tbl_607_order.order_number" + " LIKE " + "'%" + selectedOrder + "%'";


            ObservableCollection GazList = new ObservableCollection();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = GetGazQuery;
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    Gaz gaz = new Gaz
                                    {
                                        Gaz_type = reader.GetString(0),
                                        Theorical_content = reader.GetString(1),
                                        Made_tolerance = reader.GetDouble(2),
                                        Gaz_lifetime = reader.GetInt32(3),
                                        Gaz_comments = reader.GetString(4),
                                        Poste_number = reader.GetInt32(6)
                                    };

                                    GazList.Add(gaz);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return GazList;
            }
            catch (Exception eSql)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + eSql.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
    private string selectedOrder;
        public Gestion_Stock()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            SelectOrders.ItemsSource = OrdersDataHelper.GetOrders(connectionString: (Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current as App).ConnectionString);

        }

        private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Affichage_Stock_Gaz.ItemsSource = GazDataHelper.GetGaz((Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current as App).ConnectionString, selectedOrder);
        }

        private void SelectOrders_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView selectOrders = sender as ListView;
            Orders orders = SelectOrders.SelectedItem as Orders;
            selectedOrder = orders.Order_Number;

        }
```

The output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll
Exception: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'
```

This simple request is working, i don't use a variable and "where" command.

This work:

```
    static public ObservableCollection GetOrders(string connectionString)
        {
            const string GetOrdersQuery = "" +
                "select " +

                    "tbl_607_order.start_date," +
                    "tbl_607_order.end_date," +
                    "tbl_607_provider.provider_name," +
                    "tbl_607_order.order_number," +
                    "tbl_607_order.shipping_request_active," +
                    "tbl_607_order.item_reception_active " +

                "from " +
                    "tbl_607_provider join tbl_607_order on tbl_607_provider.ID = tbl_607_order.FK_ID_provider " 
                 ;
```

Someone would have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are missing a whitespace, change ´= tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order" +´ to ´= tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order " + ´

Comment: I suggest using a single verbatim string (@"") instead of this mess of contatenation. Typographical errors like this will be far less likely to occur. Also, this is vulnerable to SQL injection. Look into parameterizing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the missing space by changing

```
"SELECT " +

                    "tbl_607_gaz_type.gaz_type," +
                    "tbl_607_theorical_content.theorical_content," +
                    "tbl_607_made_tolerance.made_tolerance," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.gaz_lifetime," +
                    "tbl_607_gaz.gaz_comments," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.poste_number, " +
                    "tbl_607_order.order_number" +

                "FROM " +
                    "tbl_607_provider join tbl_607_order on tbl_607_provider.ID = tbl_607_order.FK_ID_provider " +
                    "join tbl_607_order_details on tbl_607_order.ID = tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order" +
                    "join tbl_607_gaz on tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_gaz = tbl_607_gaz.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_gaz_type on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_gaz_type = tbl_607_gaz_type.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_made_tolerance on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_made_tolerence = tbl_607_made_tolerance.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_theorical_content on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_theorical_content = tbl_607_theorical_content.ID " +

            "WHERE " +
                "tbl_607_order.order_number" + " LIKE " + "'%" + selectedOrder + "%'";
```

to

```
"SELECT " +

                    "tbl_607_gaz_type.gaz_type," +
                    "tbl_607_theorical_content.theorical_content," +
                    "tbl_607_made_tolerance.made_tolerance," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.gaz_lifetime," +
                    "tbl_607_gaz.gaz_comments," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order," +
                    "tbl_607_order_details.poste_number, " +
                    "tbl_607_order.order_number" +

                "FROM " +
                    "tbl_607_provider join tbl_607_order on tbl_607_provider.ID = tbl_607_order.FK_ID_provider " +
                    "join tbl_607_order_details on tbl_607_order.ID = tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_order " + // note the missing space added here
                    "join tbl_607_gaz on tbl_607_order_details.FK_ID_gaz = tbl_607_gaz.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_gaz_type on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_gaz_type = tbl_607_gaz_type.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_made_tolerance on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_made_tolerence = tbl_607_made_tolerance.ID " +
                    "join tbl_607_theorical_content on tbl_607_gaz.FK_ID_theorical_content = tbl_607_theorical_content.ID " +

            "WHERE " +
                "tbl_607_order.order_number" + " LIKE " + "'%" + selectedOrder + "%'";
```

Comment: Maybe it is just the SO formatting, but it looks like you are missing a space before "FROM" as well

Comment: well seen! All stupid but I spent a good half day ... The worst is that the query on SQL server administration worked without problems!